# Clustered SQL vs Hadoop

Tags: sql-server, hadoop

I am new to hadoop

Just read that Hadoop HDFS is flat-file-based

while Clustered MS SQL Server is RDBMS (no exactly sure about what it is called, but it is DB split into multiple servers and act as one database)

for a single server data I know that RDBMS is much faster than flat-file-based data, as you can index RDBMS (I hope I am not wrong by that)

If that is true, then why Hadoop which is multi server flat-file-based is faster than Clustered MS SQL Server which is multi server RDBMS?

Comment: Hadoop is more than just HDFS, so you can use a number of different RDBMS solutions on top of Hadoop. You can find various benchmarks on those to suit your needs (e.g. at https://kognitio.com/blog/how-different-sql-on-hadoop-fare-in-99-tpc-ds-test-queries/) and more detail on various products (e.g. https://jethro.io/hadoop-hive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2019 (upcoming) actually has a feature which merges both of these worlds.  You can do scale-out computations in a clustered configuration against HDFS.  You can read about it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/big-data-cluster-overview?view=sqlallproducts-allversions

An earlier version of this technology shipped in SQL Server 2016/2017 and is called Polybase.  It has a slightly different technical implementation and a different configuration experience.  You can read about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide?view=sql-server-2017

Both of these can give you a form of "scale-out compute".  Hadoop aims to take a number of relatively inexpensive nodes and do scale-out for very partitionable problems.  SQL Server can also do this, though often you can get better performance per node with the various mechanisms it has built-in.  There is a cost factor for the hardware and software (as well as the configuration/administration overhead) which is a trade-off between NoSQL and SQL-based solutions.  While there is some overlap between what you can do in these two models, the scale-out approach has some advantage for perfectly partitionable problems (either in cost or scale) and the RDBMS approach likely has richer/faster query capabilities.  That's not to say that you can't do scale-out SQL and that you can't do more complex apps in NoSQL.  They have strengths and then there is what they "can" do vs. "can't/should not" do.

(Traditional SQL Server is as the other answer suggested - somewhat more limited in terms of scale-out, though AlwaysOn Availability Groups gives you the option to build readable secondaries to do partial scale-out compute)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server cluster is a high availability solution, not a parallel compute one. Microsoft has SQL Server Parallel Warehouse (which, apparently, has Hadoop inside: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analytics-platform-system/parallel-data-warehouse-overview?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7). AlwaysOn can give some performance advantages, when read-only operations can be dont at the passive node, but in general SQL Server is a single-node solution.